# Accurev change xlink transaction

Tags: accurev

Is there a way to see stream's transaction for changed xlinks? 
I want to know when xlink was changed.
I don't see it in the history of the stream.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crosslinks (xlinks), like all other include/exclude rule changes are recorded as the "defcomp" action type and will definitely be displayed in the stream history.